# How can I migrate from avro4s 3.0.4 to 4.0.0-RC2?

Tags: scala, avro, avro4s

How can I migrate from avro4s 3.0.4 to 4.0.0-RC2?
I have the following compiling errors:

```
[error] /Users/nicolae.marasoiu/proj/data-availability-global-topic-conveyor/src/main/scala/com/ovoenergy/globaltopics/serdes/AvroFormatImplicits.scala:8:15: value const is not a member of object com.sksamuel.avro4s.SchemaFor
[error]     SchemaFor.const(new Schema.Parser().parse(getClass.getResourceAsStream(hasSchema.resourcePath)))
[error]               ^
[error] /Users/nicolae.marasoiu/proj/data-availability-global-topic-conveyor/src/main/scala/com/ovoenergy/globaltopics/serdes/AvroFormatImplicits.scala:11:26: not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit evidence$1: com.sksamuel.avro4s.Encoder[T], implicit evidence$2: com.sksamuel.avro4s.Decoder[T])com.sksamuel.avro4s.RecordFormat[T] in object RecordFormat.
[error] Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
[error]     RecordFormat.apply[T](AvroSchema[T](readSchema))
[error]                          ^
[error] /Users/nicolae.marasoiu/proj/data-availability-global-topic-conveyor/src/main/scala/com/ovoenergy/globaltopics/serdes/SerdeProvider.scala:29:37: org.apache.avro.Schema does not take parameters
[error]     val schema = SchemaFor[T].schema(DefaultFieldMapper)
[error]                                     ^
[error] /Users/nicolae.marasoiu/proj/data-availability-global-topic-conveyor/src/main/scala/com/ovoenergy/globaltopics/serdes/SerdeProvider.scala:37:70: no arguments allowed for nullary method build: ()com.sksamuel.avro4s.AvroOutputStream[T]
[error]             val os     = AvroOutputStream.binary[T].to(output).build(schema)
[error]                                                                      ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 17 s, completed 28-Jul-2020 19:42:21
[IJ]sbt:global-topic-conveyor>
```

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet you'd like to migrate?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can always follow the changes at [avro4s github repository](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s). Furthermore, you can see the [specific changes made between the versions you specified](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/compare/v3.0.4...v4.0.0-RC2).

You did not attach any source code, so I'll try to address your failures as I can understand them from your failures.

1. `SchemaFor.const` was removed at version 3.0.5 . You can see that in the [diff between the versions](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/compare/v3.0.5...v3.0.6). Assuming you had `Schema s`, and you initiated so far the `SchemaFor.const(s)`, Now you'll need to initiate it: `SchemaFor(s)`. The default fieldMapper will be used. You can see it [here](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/blob/master/avro4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/avro4s/SchemaFor.scala#L127).
2. [RecordFormat](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/blob/0205e0cbacc49f545c8c30cf466e5f0f266846e2/avro4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/avro4s/RecordFormat.scala#L16) does not take arguments anymore. Therefore assuming you had a type T, that was applied at `RecordFormat.apply[T](AvroSchema[T](readSchema))`, you need to change it into: `RecordFormat[T]`.
3. Very similar to number 1. `SchemaFor.schema` [was removed](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/blob/v3.0.4/avro4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/avro4s/SchemaFor.scala#L28). Instead, you can just do: `SchemaFor[T].schema`. [Schema](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/compare/v3.0.4...v4.0.0-RC2#diff-8a05235c28d1810859da3b817e7441c7R20) does not take parameters anymore, so you cannot call it with parentheses.
4. `AvroOutputStream.build` used to take a schema as a parameter. It doesn't take it anymore. You need to change `AvroOutputStream.binary[T].to(output).build(schema)` into: `AvroOutputStream.binary[T].to(output).build()`